# Doc2vec : TaggedLineDocument()

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

So,I'm trying to learn and understand Doc2Vec.
I'm following this [tutorial](http://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/). My input is a list of documents i.e list of lists of words. This is what my code looks like:

```
input = [["word1","word2",..."wordn"],["word1","word2",..."wordn"],...] 

documents = TaggedLineDocument(input)

model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(documents,size = 50, window = 10, min_count = 2, workers=2)
```

But I am getting some unicode error(tried googling this error, but no good ):

```
TypeError('don\'t know how to handle uri %s' % repr(uri))
```

Can somebody please help me understand where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

TaggedLineDocument should be instantiated with a file path. Make sure the file is setup in the format one document equals one line.

```
documents = TaggedLineDocument('myfile.txt')
documents = TaggedLineDocument('compressed_text.txt.gz')
```

From the [source code](https://github.com/piskvorky/smart_open/blob/master/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py):

The `uri` (the think you are instantiating TaggedLineDocument with) can be either:

```
1. a URI for the local filesystem (compressed ``.gz`` or ``.bz2`` files handled automatically):
   `./lines.txt`, `/home/joe/lines.txt.gz`, `file:///home/joe/lines.txt.bz2`
2. a URI for HDFS: `hdfs:///some/path/lines.txt`
3. a URI for Amazon's S3 (can also supply credentials inside the URI):
   `s3://my_bucket/lines.txt`, `s3://my_aws_key_id:key_secret@my_bucket/lines.txt`
4. an instance of the boto.s3.key.Key class.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **data**, I have the same formatted list as yours:

```
[['aw', 'wb', 'ce', 'uw', 'qqg'], ['g', 'e', 'ent', 'va'],['a']...]
```

For the **labels**, I have a list:

```
[1, 0, 0 ...]
```

It indicates the class of my above sentences, you can have any class(tag) at here(not only 1 or 0)

Since we already have the list like above, we can use **TaggedDocumnet** directly, instead of **TaggedLineDocument**

```
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(self.myDataFlow(data,labels))

def myDataFlow(self,data,labels):
for i, j in zip(data,labels):
    yield TaggedDocument(i,[j])
```