# doc2vec - Input Format for doc2vec training and infer_vector() in python

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

In gensim, when I give a string as input for training doc2vec model,  I get this error :

> TypeError('don\'t know how to handle uri %s' % repr(uri))

I referred to this question [Doc2vec : TaggedLineDocument()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780138/doc2vec-taggedlinedocument)
but still have a doubt about the input format.

`documents = TaggedLineDocument('myfile.txt')`

Should the myFile.txt have tokens as list of lists or separate list in each line for each document or a string?

`For eg` - I have 2 documents.

Doc 1 : Machine learning is a subfield of computer science that evolved from the study of pattern recognition.

Doc 2 :  Arthur Samuel defined machine learning as a "Field of study that gives computers the ability to learn".

So, what should the `myFile.txt` look like?

Case 1 : simple text of each document in each line

Machine learning is a subfield of computer science that evolved from the study of pattern recognition

Arthur Samuel defined machine learning as a Field of study that gives computers the ability to learn

Case 2 : a list of lists having tokens of each document

`[ ["Machine", "learning", "is", "a", "subfield", "of", "computer", "science", "that", "evolved", "from", "the", "study", "of", "pattern", "recognition"]`,

```
["Arthur", "Samuel", "defined", "machine", "learning", "as", "a", "Field", "of", "study", "that", "gives", "computers" ,"the", "ability", "to", "learn"] ]
```

Case 3 : list of tokens of each document in a separate line

```
["Machine", "learning", "is", "a", "subfield", "of", "computer", "science", "that", "evolved", "from", "the", "study", "of", "pattern", "recognition"]

["Arthur", "Samuel", "defined", "machine", "learning", "as", "a", "Field", "of", "study", "that", "gives", "computers" ,"the", "ability", "to", "learn"]
```

And when I am running it on the test data, what should be the format of the sentence which i want to predict the doc vector for? Should it be like case 1 or case 2 below or something else?

`model.infer_vector(testSentence, alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)`

Should the testSentence be :

Case 1 : string

```
testSentence = "Machine learning is an evolving field"
```

Case 2 : list of tokens

```
testSentence = ["Machine", "learning", "is", "an", "evolving", "field"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TaggedLineDocument` is a convenience class that expects its source file (or file-like object) to be space-delimited tokens, one per line. (That is, what you refer to as 'Case 1' in your 1st question.)

But you can write your own iterable object to feed to gensim `Doc2Vec` as the `documents` corpus, as long as this corpus (1) iterably-returns `next()` objects that, like TaggedDocument, have `words` and `tags` lists; and (2) can be iterated over multiple times, for the multiple passes `Doc2Vec` requires for both the initial vocabulary-survey and then `iter` training passes.

The `infer_vector()` method takes lists-of-tokens, similar to the `words` attribute of individual `TaggedDocument`-like objects. (That is, what you refer to as 'Case 2' in your 2nd question.)